# using Node.js, is it possible to store an aggregate in memory and use it's methods and value objects after retrieving?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, cqrs, event-sourcing

I’m building an event sourced application in Node (Typescript) using NestJS with CQRS as a learning project. I’m storing the events in EventstoreDB.

Currently when I need the Aggregate’s latest state I retrieve all events for that aggregate from the eventstore and replay them on a new created Aggregate instance (using nestjs/cqrs `[aggregate].loadFromHistory` ).
While this works in this learning project, it is not performant or good practice in an event-sourced architecture.

My goal is to store the aggregate in memory cache (`cache-manager, redis`), update the cache on every change made to the aggregate, and retrieve the aggregate from cache every time I need it.

What I’ve tried:

- using `import { instanceToPlain, plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';`
- convert the aggregate to json using `instanceToPlain`
- on retrieving, convert back to instance using `plainToInstance`

members of the aggregate that are value objects are not converted back properly.

I haven’t found a way to achieve this in Node yet. I hope there is a solution out there?